# Call actions on 2 different controllers with link_to button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to call 2 differenct actions with a link_to button.  When I place the following code the button only shows as a blue link and the 2nd action is not called.  Does anybody know a strategy to get around this?

```
<%= link_to "Remove from Cabinet", { :controller => 'devices', :action => 'detach_device_from_cabinet', :id => device.id }, 
            { :controller => 'cabinets', :action => 'unmark_validated', :id => @cabinet.id }, :class => "btn btn-danger", :confirm => "Detach Device: are you sure?" %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good practice to call multiple controller actions from a single link_to. You're adding too much logic to a view.

There's a rails design pattern called 'fat model, skinny controller'. You want all of your business logic done in the model, and a controller to just call the model's methods. In this specific example, you want to detach devices from a cabinet, and each device can be on one cabinet, and each cabinet can hold multiple devices.

I haven't checked this code, but it should be close to what you want:

`cabinet.rb`

```
class Cabinet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
  ...

  def self.detach_device(id)
    cabinet = Cabinet.where(device: id).first
    cabinet.devices.drop(id)
    cabinet.unmark_validated
  end

  def unmark_validated
     cabinet.marked == false
  end
end
```

`device.rb`

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cabinet
  ...

end
```

`cabinets_controller.rb`

```
class CabinetsController < ApplicationController
  def detach_from_cabinet
    @cabinet = Cabinet.detach_device(params[id])

  end
end
```

`<%= link_to "Remove from Cabinet", :controller => 'cabinets', :action => 'detach_device', id => device.id %>`

Comment: Thanks for the fat/skinny analogy.  That helps me understand the architecture a bit more.  What are helpers for then?

Comment: Helpers allow you to keep code out of your views. Some common helpers are `link_to` `button_to` `form_for`. If you are not familiar yet, railscasts.com is a great resource that a lot of rails developers use frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I never though that before, I don't get the logic, but you should make a refactoring... Call an action, send the data, and that action can call a function that execute the other stuff you want to do. Also, you should use an alias, define it in the route.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation in that I needed users to push a button in one models view and create a new row in a different model's controller, then simultaneously, change a boolean attribute in the source model.  I ended up thinning my controller and creating a new method in the corresponding model and pointing to it in the action. Piggybacking on @John's answer, here's what worked for me and could be an alternative strategy for you or anyone needing more than one action performed on one user push of the button, and possibly between more than one model:

FOO CONTROLLER/NEW

```
 def new
    ...
    # After button is pushed sending params to this action, thusly 
    # creating the new row, and saving it 
    @foo.save
    # Then to the newly created method
    @foo.new_method 
    # and back for a redirect
    redirect_to :foos, notice: "..."
  end
```

foo.rb

```
  def new_method
    @bar = Bar.find_by(:attribute => true)
    # Simply need to fllip attribute from true to false
    if @bar.attribute == true
      @bar.attribute = false
    end
    @bar.save
  end
```